# Windows Update Service eats my CPU for days on end

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

So the Windows Update Service is eating a whole core of my CPU persistently. Here is my sad story: Yesterday I noticed that "Service Host" was eating ~30% of my CPU. This turned out to be the update service thread as Process Explorer showed me:

[image]

I figure that I just have new updates, so I ignored it all day. This morning I woke my PC back up and found that I had the same problem. Update service is running at full bore. I restarted my PC. It restarted normally, but I noticed MS Installer running. After a couple minutes the MS Installer is done and the PC returns to its status-quo with the Update Service still running. I then attempt to stop the update service from the command line and get this message:

[image]

So what gives? My computer was on for ~9 hours yesterday, this should be more than enough for Windows Update to finish its stuff.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason a second restart solved my problem, no more Windows Update running. Seems like something is wrong, like Windows Update gets stuck in a loop.